# Getting the top 3 numbers in a list from infile - python

Tags: python

Sample infile - "infile name = "people"
[Name, Age]
how would I go about getting the 3 oldest people from my infile?

```
["Susan", "34"],
["Mark", "45"],
["Richard", "77"],
["Alex", "5"],
["Karen", "66"]
```

I've tried using a

```
for i, a in enumerate(people):
```

while it lists the indexes out for me, it also splits the list and creates new lines for each substring.

```
people[1]
```

would get me the substring for age, but I don't know how to compare it to other indexes.

Comment: can you be bit clear on infile...

Comment: `a[1]` would be the age

Comment: The content in the uppermost code segment doesn't look like a regular inifile. Also is your version of the file mixing " and ' as quote characters, or was it an error while writing it down?

Comment: Yes the single quote should be a double, was just an error while writing it down.

Comment: Does the file literally contain brackets and quotes?

Comment: no, i just put them there so it can easily be read. i've used `file.read().split(',')` in my code so that would be how it looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same using operator

```
import operator
a=[["Susan", "34"],
['Mark', "45"],
['Richard', "77"],
["Alex", "5"],
["Karen", "66"]]
a.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
a[:3]
```

Answer (score 3):

I am going to assume you want the 3 oldest people in list of list:

```
a=[["Susan", "34"],
['Mark', "45"],
['Richard', "77"],
["Alex", "5"],
["Karen", "66"]]
a.sort(reverse=True,key=lambda x:int(x[1]))
a[:3]
```